# Laravel WSOD on fresh install w/o log error message

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, wsod

Just another Laravel 4 white screen with no clues.

My context:

- Server CentOS 6.5
- Apache 2.2.15
- PHP 5.4.23
- php mcrypt enabled
- php log_errors working
- Laravel fresh install: "$ laravel new project"
- storage folder permissions 777
- there is **no laravel error log**
- there are **no errors on php log**
- there are **no errors on apache/httpd log**

I've tried to do a "manual debug" and the app stops at **start.php**:

```
$app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
```

Going deeper **compiled.php** I've lost track on the **share** method call:

```
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app['events'] = $this->app->share(function ($app) {
            return new Dispatcher($app);
        });
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Checked same "**500 Server Internal Error**" using Laravel's server (`$ php artisan serve`).

Comment: Need more info here mate, have you checked the apache error logs at /var/log/httpd?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that. No errors on httpd/error_log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no error log message it's probably an error log configuration problem.

Check out all php log related params at **php.ini**:

```
log_errors = On
error_reporting = E_ALL   // or 32767
error_log = syslog        // log file, 'syslog' value usually means /var/log/messages
                          //   or /var/log/syslog

display_errors = On          // print errors on screen if you're not
display_startup_errors = On  //   in a production environment
```

In case you're running Apache/VirtualHost, check it out **httpd.conf** for an alternative log file

```
<VirtualHost>
    ErrorLog /var/www/example.com/error_log
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running Laravel's server to debug possible errors in your webserver.

```
php artisan serve
```

You should have access to **localhost:8000**

If it does not display Laravel's splash page, then there can be a problem with Composer. If it display the splash page, it could be

- Apache configuration
- app/storage directory and subdirectories not being writable by PHP

Also you can check Laravel logs for errors in addition to Apache error logs

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Laravel's server gives me a "**500 Internal Server Error**" response. Laravel's storage/logs folder is empty.

Comment: Have you set the permissions correctly on your index.php?

Comment: Owner, group and read permissions are correct for the whole project. Do you mean that?

Comment: Try 755 on index.php, if that doesn't work check if mod_rewrite is enabled on the server. Can you see the start page?

Comment: Nothing changes. Yes, I have other php-simple-pages on the same server, mod_rewrite is working properly (and so the logs). In fact, I've created the Laravel project in a subfolder, that could be a problem??